# Нужна помощь с разъяснением архитектуры Clean Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Я пытаюсь разобраться с этой архитектурой, но никак не могу уловить один момент. В статье написано:

> The view controller’s output connects to the interactor’s input. The
>   interactor’s output connects to the presenter’s input. The presenter’s
>   output connects to the view controller’s input.

Согласно такому утверждению, класс ViewController выглядит вот так:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerInput {
    var output: ViewControllerOutput!
    var router: RouterInput!
}
extension ViewController: PresenterOutput {}
```

Интерактор же, в свою очередь, вот такой:

```
class Interactor: InteractorInput {
    var output: InteractorOutput!
    var worker: Worker!
}
extension Interactor: ViewControllerOutput {}
```

Если мне нужно реализовать функцию doSomething(), я должен добавить ее в протоколы InteractorInput и ViewControllerOutput, после чего во ViewController вызвать:

```
output.doSomething()
```

Почему я не могу миновать протокол InteractorInput, реализовав этот метод сразу в расширении Interactor: ViewControllerOutput? Это сделано просто для, скажем, "удобочитаемости" или есть еще какие-то важные моменты?

Comment: Не уверен, но мне кажется если вы минуете протокол и реализуете метод сразу в расширение, то он не будет виден из вне. Т.е. когда вы попытаетесь вызвать output.doSomething(), компилятор скажет, что такого метода нет.

Comment: @VitaliEller, к сожалению это не так. Метод остается видимым, даже если я убираю его из InteractorInput протокола. Компилятор не видит его только в том случае, если метод не присутствует в протоколе ViewControllerOutput.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в vc должно быть let output: InteractorInput
Т.е ты выходишь из vc (оtput) и передаешь данные через interactorinput(вход)